# Radio Button doesn't reflect Model's value

Tags: kendo-ui, radio-button, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I have a kendo Grid for a class, and for that class I've built an editor template to produce a radio button for one of the fields.

This radio button doesn't reflect propertie's value and is always `false`, although I've checked the value, by printing it on the form, and I'm sure it's `true`. If I set a default value for that field, the radio button will reflect that value, regardless of the real value of the field.

I should note that I'm using a client template to display a text for that field, and it works fine.

This is the Grid:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Class>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.BActive).ClientTemplate("#= BActive ? 'Open':'Close' #");
/// removed for brevity
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
            .Model(model => {
                model.Id(x => x.SWhCode);
                model.Field(x => x.BActive).DefaultValue(true);
            })
        )
    )
```

And this is the lines that produce the radio button inside the `editorTemplate`:

```
<label>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.BActive, true, new { @class = "radio-inline" }) Open
</label>
<label>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.BActive, false, new { @class = "radio-inline" }) Close
</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bool` type will be render in client like this

```
true => True
false => False
```

Have you try to inspect your element rendered in HTML? You'll see that the `bool` value transform into capitalize `string`. To overcome this you should change `true` and `false` in radio button with type `string` too.

Your view code should be like this

```
<label>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.BActive, "true", new { @class = "radio-inline" }) Open
</label>
<label>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.BActive, "false", new { @class = "radio-inline" }) Close
</label>
```